# Navigation barButton item not visible but Actionable iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift5

Here is my code for rightBarButton item:

```
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Apply",
            style: .plain,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(saveShotData)
        ) 
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
rightBarButton.isHidden = false
```

if you want it to be hidden and not working, then try

```
rightBarButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

isHidden only hides - it does not disable.  And unfortunately .isHidden doesn't adjust layout / hide the button - so if you have two right bar button items, they layout doesn't nicely update - though there are creative ways you can get around that if required.